# Haskell: Is there any easy way to check if two strings has any same characters?

Tags: haskell

For example :

"night", "day" -> False

"hello", "goodbye" - True

```
function string (ContainsSome (s:str)) = elem s string || function string (ContainsSome str) 

function string (ContainsSome "") = False
```

*Now if parameters are:*

function "hello" (ContainsSome "") ==> False even thought it should give True

Comment: That depends on your definition of "easy". Take a look at `map`, `elem`, and `any`.

Comment: I did an recursion with elem, but it cause problems with the last element, because empty String should give False and True at the same time.

Comment: Post the code you used. Hint: there's no need to every check if the empty string is in a string or vice versa.

Comment: function string (ContainsSome (s:str)) = elem s string || function string (ContainsSome str)

function string (ContainsSome "") = False

Comment: What is `ContainsSome`?

Comment: It is constructor of an data type.

Comment: Now that I'm thinking it is probably ok if it gives false with empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Set` type in [containers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Set.html).

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

hasSameChars :: String -> String -> Bool
hasSameChars s1 s2 = not $ S.disjoint (S.fromList s1) (S.fromList s2)
```

Or if you want to restrict yourself to lists,

```
import Data.List

hasSameChars :: String -> String -> Bool
hasSameChars s1 s2 = not $ null $ intersect s1 s2
```

Comment: You only need to build one `Set`.

Answer (score 1):

Given two strings `s1` and `s2`, they share a common character if there is at least one character in `s1` that occurs in `s2`.

Use `elem` to determine if a character is in `s2`.

Use `map` with the previous to determine, for *each* character in `s1`, if the character is in `s2`.

Use `or` to check if the list from the previous step contains a `True` value.

For example, `` 'n' `elem` "day" `` evaluates to `False`, but `` 'e' `elem` "goodbye" `` evaluates to `True`.

---

You can also use `any` instead of `or`. Where `or` takes a list of Boolean values and looks for `True`, `any` effectively maps a predicate over a list and then looks for `True` in the result.